# VBA cut every other row to last row in column and paste to new column, then delete empty rows

Tags: vba, excel, loops

hoping to get some help. I'm pretty novice with VBA, especially with loops. I've got data of varying lengths that that will be in column A that consists of an error string (A1,A3,A5,...) and corresponding error message (A2,A4,A6,...).

I'd like to cut the error message data (A2,A4,A6,...) and paste that into column H (H1,H3,H5,...) until the last row of data in column A. I would then like the newly emptied rows (2,4,6,...) to be deleted so I have a table of the error string in column A I can use 'Text to Column' on, and the corresponding error message in column H.

The end goal is that after doing a 'Text to Column', I will have a block of data that I can turn into a table.

If you think there is a better method than the cut-paste-delete empty row method then I'm all ears. I'd also like to bother you less so if you have a good resource for building loops of X code to the last row I'd love that as well.

Comment: To provide an optimal VBA-based answer it would be best to show examples of what the data starts as and what the result should be. The entire process can likely be done in VBA from raw data to formatted output.

Comment: data is organized as so:


A1: aa.bbbb.cccc.ddddd.eeee (an incorrect data string),
A2: error message (i.e., aa is not allowed with bbbb),
A3 and beyond repeating with similar error codes.


I have multiple sets of data, each with a varying length of the above data, that's why I would like to have one-fits-all macro that will run til the end of the data lines.


end result is a table with column headers of AA, BBBB, CCCC, DDDDD, EEEE, Error Message, and recommended fix, which I will manually enter based on the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub FormatForErrorCorrections()
    Dim i As Integer 'i always stores the current row# that the loop is operating on
    'since we'll be deleting rows, start at the bottom and work our way up
    With ActiveSheet
        For i = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -2 'every other row
            'assign value from column A to previous line column H
            .Range("H" & (i - 1)).Value = .Range("A" & i).Value
            'split A column into A:E using "." delimiter
            .Range("A" & (i - 1) & ":E" & (i - 1)) = Split(.Range("A" & (i - 1)).Value, ".")
            'delete the current row
            .Rows(i).Delete
        Next i 'i decrements by 2 until we reach 1 (Step -2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBA and loops is one possibility. Another one is to use a helper column to sort the data.

- add a helper column to the table and enter "a" and "b" into the first two cells.
- select the two cells and double-click the fill handle to fill the sequence to the last row of the table.
- sort the table by the new column
- select the cells in all the "a" rows and copy
- paste next to the "b" rows
- delete the helper column